# Finding exact device in the LAN Java / Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, lan

I'm developing a Java application which should listen on specific port on computer using Sockets. 
The another app, which will run on Android device connected to the same WiFi, should find this computer with my Java program.

How can I find the computer in the network?

I've tried it in the small LAN (where are all devices connected to 192.168.*.*) using `InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress).isReachable();` but in the bigger network (like *eduroam* or my school WiFi) I'm not able to scan whole network.

Is there another option how to connect two devices to each other apart from using Sockets and scanning whole network?

Comment: Did your Android app know the IP of the computer beforehand? Or did you just probe all addresses in your network and hoped for the response?

Comment: No, Android app doesn't know the IP address, it is exactly as you said, the app just tried all addresses and hoped for response. I know, that this is really dull, but so far I don't know, how to do it better.

Comment: Not only this is dull, but if the network is correctly designed you just won't be able to do that. Security measures won't let you. That's why it didn't work in the "big" network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your entire system requirements, but I'm thinking you could create a very small database at a hosting site (such as [this](https://db4free.net/)) and have your PC periodically upload its private IP address to that database.

Then, when you need to connect to the PC on your android device, you query the database and determine the PC's current address, then connect to the device.

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty good, I will go through it, thank you.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask more questions if you need help with actually setting it up.